# Autodesk Forge. learn.forge.viewmodels

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-forge

I'm just starting to learn. I created an application by the code written here: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/?id=learn-autodesk-forge. Start debug and open http://localhost:3000/. But my Buckets&Objects are show loading and in VSCode I have some problems:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1515:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12)
at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
```

What is it?

Comment: You can try `npm config set strict-ssl=false` and run `npm start`

Comment: In terminal I entry this, then client_id, client_secret and npm start. It does not work.

Comment: It appears that your company has very strict policy.
 - Good for local debugging
`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`
- If above doesn't work you may have to get and set a certificate file
`set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS= path/to/your/cert.pem`